# PHP seems to add in backslashes when strings are concatenated

Tags: php, sql, string, sql-server-2005

I am creating a query where I am passing in parameters and **when the string query is concatenated, there are backslashes which are added** and this makes the query not run worthy.

```
 $searchQuery = "Select * from  <table_name> where Department like
 '".$department. "' and Purchaser_Name like '%".$purchaser. "%' and
 Vendor_Name like '%".$vendor. "%' and User_Name like '%".$requester.
 "%' and PS_Account like '%".$psaccount. "%' ;";
```

this above string is converted

```
"Select * from  [dbo].[Unicard_Transactions] where Department like  \'%staff%\'  and Purchaser_Name like \'%mordica%\' and Vendor_Name like \'%crucial%\' and User_Name like \'%reeves%\' and PS_Account like \'%739000%\' "
```

Would like to know how I can go about creating a search string without the slashes.

Comment: How do you execute this query? Can we see some of that PHP code

Comment: It appears as though something is string escaping the single quotes

Comment: I have a function which uses the `$searchQuery` and I use the `sqlsrv_prepare` function call to execute the query.                            `$statement = sqlsrv_prepare($database_connection,$string);`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter values I was passing in didn't have a resultset. Though I have no answer, I have an answer. Thanks much for your responses. This community rocks !!